# twitch js bot subscription response

Tags: node.js, twitch

I am writing a bot for the twitch platform, and I want to make it respond to users who have subscribed to the channel.

I found USERNOTICE for this in the documentation https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/commands#usernotice

But I didn't quite understand how to use it.

Something like this?

```
client.on("message", () => {
    client.say(config.get('channel'), '/usernotice message');
});
```

Just call the `/usernotice` command and it should respond to this subscription message?

It's just difficult to test all this and I would like to have a more or less specific solution.

**UPDATE**

Also in old documentation I found this code

```
chatClient.onSub((channel, user) => {
    chatClient.say(channel, `Thanks to @${user} for subscribing to the channel!`);
});

chatClient.onResub((channel, user, subInfo) => {
    chatClient.say(channel, `Thanks to @${user} for subscribing to the channel for a total of ${subInfo.months} months!`);
});

chatClient.onSubGift((channel, user, subInfo) => {
    chatClient.say(channel, `Thanks to ${subInfo.gifter} for gifting a subscription to ${user}!`);
});
```

But it throws an error - TypeError: client.onSub is not a function

Is there any way to use it now?

```
chatClient.on('sub', (channel, user) => {
    chatClient.say(channel, `Thanks to @${user} for subscribing to the channel!`);
});
```

Comment: `client` I guess is TMI.js?

Comment: @BarryCarlyon 
yes, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption you are using tmi.js you should be looking at the tmi.js documentation rather than twitch's documentation. This documentation can be located [here](https://github.com/tmijs/docs/tree/gh-pages/_posts)

---

in the documentation they have an example for a subscription event which can be found here:
https://github.com/tmijs/docs/blob/gh-pages/_posts/v1.4.2/2019-03-03-Events.md#subscription

```js
client.on("subscription", (channel, username, method, message, userstate) => {
    // Do your stuff.
});
```